# Read file line by line with GNU parallel

Tags: bash, shell, unix, parallel-processing

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
chr1  1  5  ID1 HK1
chr2  2  8  ID2 HK3
...
```

I want to extract all lines for each ID and write these to a corresponding file for this ID. The following Code works just fine, but i would like to parallelize it with `GNU parallel`, as this is too slow with just one core (and I have 72):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line
    do  
        a=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 4- | cut -f -1)
        b=$(echo "$line" | cut -f -3)
        echo $b >> "$a.bed"
    done < "file"
```

I did this before with `grep`, but as some of the file have >800M lines, this was too slow either. How would i pass this to `GNU parallel` the right way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 800M lines, I think you need something faster than running a job for each line.

So how about:

```
sort --parallel=100 -k4 input.tsv |
  parallel --pipe --group-by 4 --colsep '\s+' -kN1 'cat > num{#}.bed'

newname() {
    head -n1 "$1" | parallel --colsep '\s+' mv "$1" {4}.bed
}
export -f newname
ls num*bed | parallel newname
```

On my system this does 100M lines in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out `GNU parallel` has an option to read a file line by line and pass the line as an argument: `parallel -a`.
I changed my code to:

```
parallel -j 60 -a temp ./make_file.sh {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `parallel` or `xargs -p`when you make your proces better.
Your current loop makes 3 different `cut` processes for each line in the file.
Consider cutting the cut overhead with something like

```
while IFS= read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
    do  
        echo "${f3}" >> "${f4}.bed"
    done < "file"
```